# Common method on enums that doesn't require an enum variant to be constructed

Tags: dart

I'm having problems designing a Bluetooth GATT service/characteristics type system. Basically, I have a couple of GATT services, and each service has multiple characteristics. The first thing I did is to use enums, like this:

```dart
enum Service1 {
  char1('...'),
  char2('...'),
  char3('...');

  final String id;
  const Service1(this.id);

  Uuid get uuid => Uuid.parse(id);
}

enum Service2 {
  char1('...'),
  char2('...');

  final String id;
  const Service1(this.id);

  Uuid get uuid => Uuid.parse(id);
}
```

Now, `Service1` and `Service2` both should have an additional `Uuid` that identifies the service. For example:

```dart
enum Service1 {
  char1('...'),
  char2('...'),
  char3('...');

  final String id;
  const Service1(this.id);

  Uuid get uuid => Uuid.parse(id);
  static Uuid get service => Uuid.parse('...');
}

enum Service2 {
  char1('...'),
  char2('...');

  final String id;
  const Service1(this.id);

  Uuid get uuid => Uuid.parse(id);
  static Uuid get service => Uuid.parse('...');
}
```

The reason it's `static` is because the `service` doesn't depend on a characteristic: in fact, every characteristic belongs to the same service. So far, so good. The problem I'm facing is that I would like to have a common interface to implement the `service` getter. But I cannot define an abstract static member, and every non-static member of an enum requires an enum value to be constructed. Ultimately, I would like to write `Service1.service` and *not* `Service1.char1.service`.

Is there a way to achieve this? Sealed classes come to mind, but I would like to avoid having to write the entire machinery of sealed classes for this little detail. Also Dart doesn't let me have classes inside classes, so sealed classes are a quick way to pollute the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this with plain classes or enums.
Static members are not parts of interfaces, you cannot abstract over their resolution.

You can write `Service1.service`, but you can't have an expression of the form `T.service`, where `T` is either `Service1` or `Service2`, and it accesses the static member of one of the services that way. Static member resolution happens at compile-time, there is no way around that.

You may be able to create a larger framework, with objects representing the types and instance members forwarding to the static members, but it'll be a lot of work and likely never work precisely as you want it to.

I'd just make sure that any method which takes a type argument which is one of your enums, and which will need the service ID, will also take a service UUID as argument.